# AWS S3 update image using pre-signed URL (Axios-PUT Request)

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, axios, jpeg

I'm trying to update a **local JPG image file** into an S3 bucket using the REST PUT request and Axios.

I managed to send the PUT request and to get a positive answer from AWS S3 Service **but** what it's been upload **is not a JPG file but a JSON file**.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
    //Create the FormData
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', fs.createReadStream(image_path));


   //Send the file to File-system
   console.log("Sending file to S3...");
   const axiosResponse = await axios.put(image_signed_url, {
       data: data,
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
     }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      return null;
     });
```

I have already try to change the headers to `{'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }` but I obtained the same result.

Comment: Are you sure, that the image_signed_url generated for the JPG file?

Comment: @CyberEternal I do otherwise it will be not possible to upload anything as the signature should not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did not manage to make AXIOS work in order to upload an image.

The node-fetch module did it sending the image as a binary and specifying the "Content-type".

If I try to the same using AXIOS it the image was always packet into a form-data and the result was JSON file uploaded into the S3 bucket instead of the image.

```
 //Send the file to File-system
console.log("Sending file to S3...");
const resp = await fetch(image_signed_url, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: fs.readFileSync(image_path),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
  },
}).catch( err => {
  console.log(err);
  return null;
});
```

Comment: damn axios I wasted so much time why is that??

Comment: Same here.  As soon as I used fetch it worked.  Thank you for the answer

Comment: Thanks, @Edgar. I wasted so much time getting `axios` to upload the file to S3 via the pre-signed URL. Using `fetch` solved the problem instantly. So much for using a well-known package. :)